# Derive equivalent relation using two forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, kahler-manifolds

Let $\Omega(X,Y)=g(X,JY)$ is a Kaehler 2-form, and $d\Omega=\omega\wedge\Omega$ (1), where $\omega$ is closed one-form. Relation (1) is equivalent to
$$(\nabla_XJ)Y=\frac{1}{2}[\Theta(Y)X-\omega(Y)JX-g(X,Y)A-\Omega(X,Y)B],$$
where $\Theta=\omega\circ J$, $g(X,B)=\omega(X)$, $A=-JB$.

I am trying to prove this equivalence, starting with $X\Omega(Z,Y)=Xg(Z,JY)$. And that is fine if I use $\nabla$ (Levi-Civita connection), for example $\nabla_X\Omega(Z,Y)+\Omega(\nabla_XZ,Y)+...$. But, how will I use $d$ in this case?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but you also have $X(\Omega(Z,Y)) = \mathcal L_X(\Omega(Z,Y))$. That might help introduce an exterior $d$ into the calculation, maybe?

Comment: Compute $Z\cdot\Omega(X,Y)$ in two ways: one saying it is $(L_Z\Omega)(X,Y) + \Omega(L_ZX,Y) + \Omega(X,L_ZY)$, another one saying $Z\cdot g(X,JY) =g(\nabla_ZX,JY) + g(X,\nabla_Z(JY))$. For information, what do you call a Kaehler form? It seems to me that if $\Omega$ is Kaehler, $\nabla J=0$, that is $J$ is parallel.

Comment: What do you denote by $L_X$? I would like to obtain expression for $(\nabla_XJ)Y$ from (1), by replacing $\Omega$ with $g(X,JY)$. $\Omega$ defined like this is called Kaehler, but the manifold I work with is not.

Comment: Ordinarily a Kähler form is called that if and only if it is closed. Otherwise, call it the $(1,1)$-form associated to the metric.